# buttons with different target inside form with action

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, pdo

I have a question about forms. I created a form with an action, inside the form are two buttons, one to submit the form and one to submit also but to different php file, how do I do this? here's my code:

```
<form action="viewmember.php">
<input type="text" value="Clyde">
<input type="submit" value="View" id="viewbutton">
<input type="submit" value="Delete" id="deleteButton">
 </form>
```

viewbutton works, but what I want to happen is when I click deletebutton it will submit to different php file let's say delete.php . If you asked why I include the deletebutton inside the form with addmember action is that when I click deletebutton I can also get the value of textfield with the value of "Clyde".

Comment: The most reliable way to do this is to name your buttons, then test the value of `$_POST['submit']` inside `viewmember.php` before doing anything else. If it equals `Delete`, do something else or redirect to a different script. JavaScript solutions are possible, but JavaScript might be disabled.

Comment: One day, you'll be able to use the HTML5 [`formaction`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/form-submission.html#attr-fs-formaction) attribute on the submit buttons, but browser support probably isn't wide enough yet. In the meantime, use a server-side solution as described in various answers.

Answer (score 6):

Give it a name:

```
<form action="viewmember.php" method="POST"> 
<input type="text" value="Clyde">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Add" id="viewbutton">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" id="deleteButton">
 </form>
```

Then

```
<?php

$action = $_POST['action'];

if($action == "Add")
{
   // add
}
elseif($action == "Delete")
{
   // delete
}

?>
```

Comment: Ofcourse it works, this is one of the best ways I know to check this server side ;)

Answer (score 1):

You would need some javascript magic.

```
$(function(){
     var form = $('form').on('submit', function(){
          return false;
    });
    $('input[value="View"]', form).on('click', function(){
          form.attr('action', 'viewmember.php')[0].submit();
    });
    $('input[value="Delete"]', form).on('click', function(){
          form.attr('action', 'deletemember.php')[0].submit();
    });
});
```

Above is all untested, but in theory, it should work.

Comment: Unreliable. The user can always disable JavaScript.

Comment: @Blazemonger yes, yes they can. Then you would have to have some checking on the server side to make sure the data does not get corrupted.

Comment: @Robuust yes, yes there are. The OP wanted to know how to do it on the client side. and this is one possible way.

Comment: Yes, you can check with JS first and also with PHP to have a double security if user disables JS. And indeed, it should work what you said.

Comment: @Robuust hence my earlier comment to Blazemonger ^_^

Answer (score 0):

An HTML form always has one action. If you need to provide different actions from one form use something like a controller dispatcher, which reads the button values and processes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, instead of having two separate php files, is have one php file.  Then inside that file you have:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['View'])) { Do all your view stuff here } ?>
```

then you could do another:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['Delete'])) { Do delete stuff here } ?>
```

Remember you will need to add a method to your form, either POST or GET.  In this case, you will need to use POST.

Thats one way of doing it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this. It will work

```
 <form action="viewMember.php" name='form1"><input type="submit" onclick="form1.action='otherUrl'; return true;" /><input type="submit"/></form>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.